# Packing Slip data not sent with Paypal Payments Pro Gateway in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, paypal

we're using EE 2.6.1 and Store 1.6.4, and are utilizing the Paypal Pro payment method. We got things working mostly, however there are some issues with the data as we see it within Paypal, so I'm thinking the data isn't getting passed to Paypal correctly or completely.

The first issue I noticed was after I submitted an order, in PayPal when I viewed the details of the order, it would have something like "Order #242" as the "Item Title". This wasn't very useful for me. It would be ideal if this could list all of the individual items and their quantities, but I'm not sure how to get it to do that. I did modify the payment gateway to list the individual items and quantities in this "Item title" section... so that kinda works.

The remaining issue is with the Packing Slip in Paypal. When I view the packing slip for the order in paypal, for "Address" it says "No Address Provided"... not showing the buyers address. That is crucial! Also, it doesn't list each individual item, but instead lists Qty: 1, Website: (our website url), Item Number: n/a, Description: (Buyer Name), Amount: (total amount). Then it lists $0.00 for shipping and handling and $0.00 for Sales Tax.

Is anyone else having this issue? Am I doing something wrong, or is this Paypal Pro payment gateway just really not fully fleshed out?

Thanks!

Gary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: As of Store 2.1, PayPal Express supports passing line item details via PayPal Express. I believe this won't work with PayPal Pro yet though, as the syntax is slightly different.

ORIGINAL: Store doesn't pass individual line item prices through to PayPal. This is a feature request we are working on, but for now "Order #242" is all you will see in Paypal, and you will need to look in the Store control panel for the full order details.

Likewise, the shipping address is not currently passed through either. It's probably easier if you print your packing slips from your EE control panel instead of Paypal.

Comment: It looks like Store 2.1 is now passing individual item information over to paypal! 

https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html